# How to sign up with devise user and ignore some validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I have a setup devise for user signup, this is working and so are the password validations that come by default. I have updated that devise model to include other fields like hometown, address, etc. I still want the user to be able to sign up by only providing email and password. When I added validations for fields like address, gender, etc, when a user wants to sign up, it will complain that those fields are empty. How can I ignore specific validations such as address, gender, etc, without ignoring the password validation that came by default? I saw something about using a flag inside `.save(:validate => false)` but I don't want to use this because it will ignore password validation.

Is there a way to solve this without having to create an additional model? User and UserAdditionalInfo? I want everything in User.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you add the validation for address, say `:allow_blank => true`

For eg:

```
validates_length_of :address, :maximum => 30, :allow_blank => true
```

This will allow you to create a user without checking the address length.

Comment: Thanks! I also saw a similar option just now for allow_nil.